# Como criar uma subpasta a cada qrcode gerado com o nome da pessoa e inserir o .png lá dentro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qrcode, diretório

import qrcode
import os

text = input('Nome completo: ')

img = qrcode.make(text) #Gera o QRCODE
img.save(f'{text}.png') #Salva e renomeia o QRCODE para o nome da pessoa +.png

---

#Ex: Nome completo: João Menezes
#Começa a gerar o qr code com o nome da pessoa

#criar uma pasta/subpasta com o nome da pessoa

#insere o João Menezes.png dentro desta página

---

#Nomes (pasta principal)

#Maria Júlia (subpasta) > /Maria Júlia.png
#Pedro Álvares (subpasta) > /Pedro Álvares.png
#João Menezes (subpasta) > /João Menezes.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from os import mkdir    
from qrcode import make

name = input('Nome completo: ')
mkdir(f'{name}')
qrcode_image = make(name)
qrcode_image.save(f'{name}\\{name}.png')
```

O método `mkdir` do pacote `os` pode criar pastas e subpastas. Dessa forma, recebemos o nome do usuário, em seguida criamos a pasta, e depois criamos e salvamos o QR Code dentro da pasta criada, com o nome fornecido pelo usuário, com a extensão `PNG`. Devo ressaltar que, importei apenas os métodos necessários para a execução do programa conforme os requisitos propostos, isso diminui a quantidade de memória a ser utilizada pelo programa, além de ser considerada uma boa prática por muitos, já que estamos sendo objetivos e diretos sobre o que desejamos utilizar, consequentemente, definir explicitamente o que devemos importar. Espero que tenha o ajudado.